# Searching for array of needle values with strpos()

Tags: php

I'm trying to use strpos to search for some key words in a string using PHP. My question is how would I go about adding a array so I search for "keyword1" and "keyword2" to the code below.

```
if (strpos($string,'keyword1') !== false) {
$hasstring = "yes";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific? I have no idea what you're trying to achieve..

Comment: Are you searching for either KW1 or KW2? I don't understand why you say you want to add an array -- that confuses the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using an array as needles in strpos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284553/using-an-array-as-needles-in-strpos)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, an array is not needed. You can simply use strpos twice with an or (in php, ||) operator

```
if (strpos($string,'keyword1') || strpos($string,'keyword2')) {
$hasstring = "yes";
}
```

Comment: This only accounts for 2 keywords, what about "n" keywords?

Comment: I think array could also be a possibility if you are searching for a list of possible keywords in a text file. E.G search for tech skills in a resume, array could content $skills =(Html, Java, PHP, mysql, Oracle, android)

Answer (score 8):

You can't give `strpos` an array, so you will have to do it manually.

```
$keywords = array('keyword1', 'keyword2');

foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
    if (strpos($string, $keyword) !== false) {
        $hasString = true;
        break; // stops searching the rest of the keywords if one was found
    }
}
```