# How do I check if a certain set of words is in a string with PHP

Tags: php, string, variables

So I have this code below but I am wondering how I can tell if '$text' contains the words 'by owner'.  How do I do this?  I looked around but I can't find anything.

```
foreach($anchors as $a) { 
    $i = $i + 1;
    $text = $a->nodeValue;
    $href = $a->getAttribute('href');
    if ($i > 22 && $i < 64 && ($i % 2) == 0) {
        //if ($i<80) {
         echo "<a href =' ".$href." '>".$text."</a><br/>";
    }
   // }
        //$str = file_get_contents($href);
//$result = (substr_count(strip_tags($str),"ipod"));
//echo ($result);
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to check if `$text` has the substring `"by owner"`?  Cause http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php will do that...  If you need case insensitivity, use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php .  And http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php will allow you to use regular expressions to match variable spacing, exact words, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$text = $a->nodeValue;
if(strpos($text, "by owner") == -1){  // if you want the text to *start* with "by owner", you can replace this with strpos($text, "by owner") != 0
    echo "Doesn't have by owner";
}
else{
    echo "Has by owner";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way that I could check for multiple sub strings?

Comment: As far as I know, PHP doesn't have that function. But you can build one yourself. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9220624/898423 for an example.