# strpos to find multiple words?

Tags: php

Can you please tell me how can I use `strops` to see if a string doesn't contains any of the two specific words? (`?` and `if`)

```
$phrase = “how to use strops?”
if(strpos($phrase, "?|if") === false) //Is there a way I can detect the presence of
{               //either words in a sentence using one line of code that has strpos

     echo “neither word is found”;
}
```

Comment: `strpos` tells you the 1st occurrence of a string in another string.  It may not be the best choice to use here.  If you want to use it, you'll need to use it twice; once for `?` and once for `if`.

Comment: Can't you just use `preg_match` for this? `preg_match('/\?|if/', $phrase);`

Comment: "using one line of code that has strpos" sounds a little like homework. You should also note that "strpos" does not detect "words", it detects occurences. "if" would match "lift", "swift", "if", etc. But to answer your question: `if((strpos($phrase,"?") || strpos($phrase,"if")) === false)` is one line.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers and comments. `if((strpos($phrase,"?") || strpos($phrase,"if")) === false)` would be the best way for me. thanks Jacob s

Comment: `“` and `”` are not valid string delimiters anyways. don't use a wordprocessor to edit code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using an array as needles in strpos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284553/using-an-array-as-needles-in-strpos)

Answer (score 2):

`strpos()` does not support regular expression. So you either use regexps (like `preg_match()` or do something less sophisticated like:

```
$phrase = "how to use strpos";
$words = array('foo', 'bar');

$matches = 0;
foreach( $words as $word ) {
   $matches += ( strpos( $phrase, $word ) !== false ) ? 1 : 0;
}

printf("%d words matches", $matches);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if ((strpos($phrase, "?")===FALSE)$$(strpos($phrase,"if")===FALSE)) echo "neither word is found";
```

Comment: `strpos` can return `0`, which means "start of the string".  You should use `strpos() === FALSE` *NOT* `!strpos()`.

Comment: Didn't notice. Thank you for this and sorry for my wrong answer!