# Check if HTML code contains words

Tags: php, html, variables

How does know how I can make a PHP script that checks if a HTML code stored as a variable contain certain words?

To illustrate my problem:

```
$html = "<p>My name is Herman</p><br><span>I like to eat hamburgers</span>";
```

For example; I need a PHP script that can check if this variable contains "Herman" or "hamburger".

Thanks you :)

Comment: Please show us what you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

```
<?php
$html = "<p>My name is Herman</p><br><span>I like to eat hamburgers</span>";

if(strpos($html, "Herman") !== false) {
    echo "string found";
} else {
    echo "string not found";
}
?>
```

Comment: But if I want to check multiple words? (like "Herman" and "Hamburger" at the same time? Thanks :)

Comment: If you want to check if "Herman" or "hamburger" exists in the string, use `strpos($html, "Herman") !== false || strpos($html, "hamburger") !== false` Using `&&` instead of `||` returns true only if both words exist in the string. Otherwise, check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284553/using-an-array-as-needles-in-strpos

Comment: Isn't it a easier way to to it (like using an array)? :)

Comment: Did you check the link I sent you?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use function strtolower to make your search case insensitive, then use strpos. It will find the numeric position of the first occurrence of your search in the haystack string return 0 if not found.

```
$lowhtml=strtolower($html);
if((strpos($lowhtml, 'hamburger')!=false) && (strpos($lowhtml, 'herman')!=false)){
    echo "Contains";
}else{
    echo "Doesn't contain";
}
```

Comment: Indexing starts at zero, so your answer is invalid. The function returns false if the string was not found. Also, did the asker ask about case insensitive search?

Comment: Seems you edited your answer. You can't use `!= false`. Quote from the PHP docs: `This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.`

Comment: Yes I have. I wasn't quite sure how to communicate to you. Still getting used to the site. Thanks a lot for your corrections and sorry for wasting your time.