# See if one item in array is true

Tags: php, css, arrays, if-statement, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to put a menu together where it will sense what page is loaded.  This site is not done in a CMS and is straight PHP/HTML code.

I currently have the navigation working for the primary links.  There is a dropdown where I am having problems.  I need to be able to see if the parent or any dropdown children are active.  If one of the children are active. In the example below this is "FAQ" and the children are "FAQ1," "FAQ2," and "FAQ3."

For this example I'm using a CSS state called "active."

```
<style>
a{color:red;}
.active{color:blue;}
</style>
```

Here is the script used for the menu.  The links for Home, Products, and Contact are working as expected.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php" id="homenav" <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) echo 'class="active"';?>>Home</a></li>
<li><a href="products.php" id ="prodnav" <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'products.php')) echo 'class="active"';?>>Products</a></li>
<li><a href="faq.php" id ="faqnav" <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'faq.php, faq1.php, faq2.php, faq3.php')) echo 'class="active"';?>>FAQ</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="faq1.php">FAQ1</a></li>
        <li><a href="faq2.php">FAQ2</a></li>
        <li><a href="faq3.php">FAQ3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="contact.php" id ="connav" <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'contact.php')) echo 'class="active"';?>>contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can I please get some help on how I should be writing this line to let it work the way the others are?

```
<li>
    <a href="faq.php" id ="faqnav" 
    <?php 
    if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'faq.php, faq1.php, faq2.php, faq3.php')) 
    echo 'class="active"'; 
    ?>
    >FAQ</a>
</li>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284553/using-an-array-as-needles-in-strpos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strpos() only accepts one string per parameter, you can not give it a list.
Try this:

`<?php if (in_array(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), array('faq.php', 'faq1.php', 'faq2.php', 'faq3.php'))) echo 'class="active"';?>`

- `basename()` strips the path from the filename, so you only have the pure file name
- `in_array()` then checks if this path is in an array
- `array()` generates an array of strings to be handed over to `in_array()`. Note that there are 4 separate strings, not one long one as in your code.

Comment: Your code gave me an error message.  However changing it to: `<?php if (in_array(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), array('faq.php', 'faq1.php', 'faq2.php', 'faq3.php'))) echo 'class="active"';?>` works.  It was missing a closing ).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `in_array` for this purpose:

```
if (in_array($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], array('faq.php', 'faq1.php', 'faq2.php', 'faq3.php')) echo 'class="active"';
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php

Comment: `in_array` is not equivalent to `strpos` in this case. For example, if `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == 'en/faq.php'` then `strpos` would correctly recognize you as being on the FAQ page while the `in_array` solution would not. MrTweeks answer is better, in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any other pages that contain `faq`, you can simply use:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'faq') !== false)
```

Note that I am using `!== false` as `strpos` can return `0` when `faq` is found at the beginning of your string. You should probably use that for your other comparisons too.

Otherwise, go with the `in_array` solution of @MrTweek.