# check if string exists in array element

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any function that can do what `strpos` does, but on the elements of an array ? for example I have this array :

```
    Array
(
 [0] => a66,b30
 [1] => b30
)
```

each element of the array can contain a set of strings, separated by commas.

Let's say i'm looking for b30.
I want that function to browse the array and return 0 and 1. can you help please ? the function has to do the oppsite of what [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9220624/2983862) does.

Comment: well, what have you tried so far? you know we expect that you try something. Show some code.

Comment: `$check = 'b30'; $result = array_filter($myArray, function ($value) use ($check) { return strpos($value, $check) !== false; } );`

Comment: When you say :  " I want that function to browse the array and return 0 and 1" , you mean 1 for each array containing the string, or if one if there is at least 1 array containing the string ?

Comment: @CodeGodie I tried the `in_array` function but it did not work (need to split what's on the element first)

Comment: have you tried `explode`?

Comment: i can indeed use explode and then read from the result...but with every element of my initial array i will have an array of exploded values. i'm looking for a fancier way :)

Comment: @MarkBaker +1 thanks ! those two tiny lines of code do exactly what i wanted. please answer my question so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested) :

```
function arraySearch($array, $search) {
    if(!is_array($array)) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(is_array($search) || is_object($search)) {
        return 0;
    }
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if(is_array($v) || is_object($v)) {
            continue;
        }
        if(strpos($v, $search) !== false) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) for this.

```
<?php

$a = array(
 'j98',
 'a66,b30',
 'b30',
 'something',
 'a40'
);

print_r( count(preg_grep('/(^|,)(b30)(,|$)/', $a)) ? 1 : 0 );
```

https://eval.in/412598