# Check URL for matching terms in array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to check a URL, to see if it has any matching terms from my array.

My code is:

```
function test_string_in_url () {

$the_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$my_array = array(
    'word1',
    'word2',
    'word3',
);

if (strpos( $the_url, $my_array ) !== false)
    // do something

    else {
    // do nothing
    }
}
```

This always returns false though, which is incorrect.
It should only return true because I do have matching terms in my URL, so I must be doing something wrong here...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an array as needles in strpos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284553/using-an-array-as-needles-in-strpos)

Comment: @rtfm - I tried the solution in there, but it does not work in my case sorry

Comment: please try my below code and let me know its working for you

Comment: post what you actually tried, because there's no reason that the answer from the other post should not have worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code

```
$my_array = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
$the_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
foreach ($my_array as $url) {

    if (strpos($the_url, $url) !== FALSE) { 
        echo "Match found"; 
        return true;
    }
}
echo "Not found!";
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

**It is returning false because you are passing array as needle to strpos which accepts only integer or string as parameter thats why it was returning false always.Check the solution this resolves it.**

```
<?php

function test_string_in_url () {

 $the_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] .     $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

 $my_array = array(
'word1',
'word2',
'word3');
foreach($my_array as $val)
{
    if (strpos( $the_url, $val) !== false)
    {
       //do something
        break;
    }
else {
        // do nothing
}
}//foreach
}//function
test_string_in_url ();
?>
```