# How can I hide a string if it doesn't contain one of multiple words?

Tags: php

I already have a code:

```
  <?
           $eventname = $event->title;
           $bad_words = array('Example1','Example2','Example3','Example4','Example5','Example6');

           foreach($bad_words as $bad_word){
               if(strpos($eventname, $bad_word) !== false) {
                 echo '';
                 break;
               }
               else {
                 echo '<div class="uk-text-contrast">'.translate('HIDDEN_INFO_DATE').'</div>';
                 break;
               }
           }
           ?>
```

this works, but only if the `$eventname` contains `example1`. But I want to hide                  `echo '<div class="uk-text-contrast">'.translate('HIDDEN_INFO_DATE').'</div>';` from all of the defined words in the `$bad_words`.

How can I hide the `echo` if there is one of the `$bad_words`?

Comment: might be worth a ganders - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284553/using-an-array-as-needles-in-strpos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the in_array function? It's even shorter in that way.

```
if (in_array($eventname, $bad_words)) {
    echo '';
} else {
    echo '<div>';
}
```

Comment: This works, but it displays the output of the `echo '<div>';` multiple times on a page that doesn't contain `$bad_words`

Comment: What do you want to display on that page then?

Comment: Okay, this code works if I add a break to the second `echo`. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: But how would I be able to do it without it? I need to hide the `<div>` if ONE of the  `$bad_words` triggers it.

Answer (score 0):

remobe 'break' from code

```
foreach($bad_words as $bad_word){
               if(strpos($eventname, $bad_word) !== false) {
                 echo '';
               }
               else {
                 echo '<div class="uk-text-contrast">'.translate('HIDDEN_INFO_DATE').'</div>';
               }
           }
```

Comment: yes, but I need to prevent that it runs the second echo if even one of the words triggers it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a loop, you could split the title into it's separate words and then check if there are any words in the `$bad_words` list using `array_intersect()`

```
// $eventname = $event->title;
$eventname = 'Some text';
$eventname = 'Some text Example1';
$bad_words = array('Example1','Example2','Example3','Example4','Example5','Example6');

$eventWords = explode(" ", $eventname);
if ( empty (array_intersect($eventWords, $bad_words)))  {
    // Event name is OK
    echo $eventname;
}
```

This has some examples to show how it works.

Note that this code doesn't pick up things like `Example1234` which `strpos()` would.

**Update:**

Just to make it more flexible, you can use regular expressions in case you have punctuation in the title...

```
$eventname = 'Some text';
$eventname = 'Some text,Example1';
$bad_words = array('Example1','Example2','Example3','Example4','Example5','Example6');

preg_match_all('/(\w+)/', $eventname, $eventWords);

if ( empty (array_intersect($eventWords[1], $bad_words)))  {
    echo '<div class="uk-text-contrast">'.translate('HIDDEN_INFO_DATE').'</div>';
}
```

( Note: Regular expressions aren't my subject so please let me know if this needs to be improved).

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the string $eventname to an array and then use the [array Intersect function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
    $eventname = "sgswfdg Example1 sdfh dh  dfa hadhadh";   
$title_to_array=explode(" ", $eventname);
$bad_words = array('Example1','Example2','Example3','Example4','Example5','Example6');

$result = !empty(array_intersect($bad_words , $title_to_array ));

if ($result){
    echo '';
    } else {
    echo $eventname;
}
```