# How to Get Multiple values can become single using php

Tags: php, strpos

I am a new person in the PHP. I have one String.I use this to find a word for `strpos` function
for example..

```
$a= "google" ;
$b= "google is best one" ;

  if(strpos($b, $a) !== false) {
echo "true, " ; // Working Fine...

}
```

so i want to in this case  check My Example

```
$a= "google,yahoo,Bing" ;
$b= "Bing is Good " ;

  if(strpos($b, $a) !== false) {
echo "true, " ; // I Need True...

}
```

This is how you do PHP

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are asking.

Comment: Put the names in an array, and then loop through the array, each time checking the current value against `$b`.

Comment: @Patrick Q Please Give Example for my Qustion

Comment: I gave you enough for you to be able to make an attempt.  Try it yourself, and feel free to update the question with your progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string on the comma using explode() and then check each of the parts individually:

```
$a= "google,yahoo,Bing" ;
$b= "Bing is Good " ;

$parts = explode(',', $a);

foreach ($parts as $part) {

    if(strpos($b, $part) !== false) {
        echo "true, " ; // I Need True...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, it looks like you're trying to perform a match such that any value in a list of values from `$a` is present in `$b`. This is not possible with a simple `strpos()` call because `strpos()` looks for the exact occurrence of the string you're passing in.

What you're attempting to do is a pattern-based search. To make this work, please look into using a regular expression with `preg_match()`. Such an example could look like this:

```
$pattern = '/google|yahoo|Bing/';
$target_string = 'Bing is good';

if(preg_match($pattern, $target_string)) {
    echo "true, ";
}
```

For more information, look into regular expression syntax and play around with it until you're familiar with how they work.

Comment: I Need to `$pattern` with comma seprate ?

Comment: Please review regular expression syntax. For a regular expression to work, you need to use the pipe `|` character as a delimiter, not a comma `,`. If you only have a comma-separated list of values, then you need to transform the string using some kind of `str_replace()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Like Patrick Q said put names in an array example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284553/using-an-array-as-needles-in-strpos)

becuase you are searching all three words "google,yahoo,Bing" which can not be true.

but for beginner to understand other way.

```
$a[0]= "google";
$a[1]= "yahoo";
$a[2]= "Bing";
$b= "Bing is Good";
strpos($b, $a[0]); // false
strpos($b, $a[1]); // false
strpos($b, $a[2]); // true as Bing found
```

also you can loop through to check

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your issue with a regular expression:

```
if (preg_match('/string1|string2|string3/i', $str)){
  //if one of them found
}else{
  //all of them can not found
}
```

Comment: Please use the `Preview` function to check your answer is formatted appropriately before posting it.