# how to check presence of certain character in a variable using php

Tags: php

Am using code below to check presence of certain character via php and it works fine.

with code below, I can check if character **a** is presence in the variable and is working.

```
$mystring = 'my food is okay. its delicious';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
if ($pos !== false) {
echo 'data found';
}
```

**Here is my issue:** I need to check the also presence of multiple characters like **m,e,s** etc. any idea on how to achieve that.

Comment: `m AND e AND s` or `m OR e OR s` ???

Comment: Are all characters required or do you you just need to make sure at least one exists? Does it matter which order they are in?

Comment: Thanks alot .it works like charm. could you update so that i can select it as answer

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/q/6284553/296555

Comment: What works?  That was a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, from using multiple `strpos` to comparisons after a `str_replace`.  Here we can split the string into an array and calculate the intersection with another array:

```
$mystring = 'my food is okay. its delicious';
$findme   = ['m', 'e', 's'];
```

Check for ANY of the characters in the array:

```
if(array_intersect($findme, str_split($mystring))) {
    echo "1 or more found";
}
```

Check for ALL of the characters in the array:

```
if(array_intersect($findme, str_split($mystring)) == $findme) {
    echo "all found";
}
```

And for fun, run the array through a callback and filter it based upon whether it is in the string.  This will check for ANY:

```
if(array_filter($findme, function($v) use($mystring) {
                             return strpos($mystring, $v) !== false;
                         }))
{
    echo "1 or more found";
}
```

This will check for ALL:

```
if(array_filter($findme, function($v) use($mystring) {
                             return strpos($mystring, $v) !== false;
                         }) == $findme)
{
    echo "all found";
}
```

Comment: `!array_diff($findme, str_split($mystring))` will also work for ALL.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is with `trim`.

```
$mystring = 'my food is okay. its delicious';
$findme = 'ames';

$any = trim($findme, $mystring) != $findme;
$all = !trim($findme, $mystring);
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will do the trick for you:

```
/**
 * Takes an array of needles and searches a given string to return all
 * needles found in the string. The needles can be words, characters,
 * numbers etc.
 * 
 * @param array $needles
 * @param string $haystack
 * @return array|null
 */
function searchString(array $needles, string $haystack): ?array
{
    $itemsFound = [];
    foreach($needles as $needle) {
        if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
            $itemsFound[] = $needle;   
        }
    }

    return $itemsFound;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/5oXGp