# How to find if there are some inappropriate words in my form

Tags: php

I am trying to find out if the user has entered any inappropriate words in my registration form. I thought I would use the strpos function but not sure if the code is correct or not?

I tried using the strpos function and supplied 3 variables called $first, $find, $offset to find any inappropriate words in the $find variables for the variable $first

```
$offset = 0;
    $find = array('retard', 'stupid', 'rascist', 'bastard', 'fuck', 'fuck-off');
if (strpos($first, $find, $offset)) {
                     header("Location: ../signup.php?signup2=rudewords");
                    exit();

But I guess the error here is that I do not know how to use the array with the strpos
```

Updated code:

```
if (array_sum(array_map(function ($i) use ($first, $last, $email, $uid, $password) {
                   return strpos($first, $last, $email, $uid, $password, $i) !== FALSE;
                    }, $find)) > 0) {
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup2=badwords");
                    exit();
```

Comment: Here is the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9220624/999617

Comment: What is the text you are trying to search for these keywords?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an array as needles in strpos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284553/using-an-array-as-needles-in-strpos)

Comment: I am still confused after looking through the other posts but I am trying to search through my registration form to make sure that no rude word has been entered in my variables called $first, $last, $uid, $password etc

Comment: Please refrain from using abusive keywords in your code. You can safely replace them with `keyword1`, `keyword2`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you could use to detect bad words in your form input (using your example as a base):

```
$offset = 0;
$find = array('retard', 'stupid', 'racist', 'bastard', 'fuck', 'fuck-off');
$first = "you're a fuckin' stupid";

if (array_sum(array_map(function ($i) use ($first) {
    return strpos($first, $i) !== FALSE;
}, $find)) > 0) {
    echo "BAD!";
}
```

If you want this synthesized into a quick function, it could be something like this:

```
function has_bad_words($input, $badwords) {
    $output = false;

    if (!empty($input)) {
        if (!empty($badwords)) {
            if (is_array($badwords)) {
                $output = array_sum(array_map(function ($i) use ($input) {
                    return strpos($input, $i) !== FALSE;
                }, $badwords)) > 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

There's an even better approach. If you use [this](https://github.com/snipe/banbuilder) library, it will do what you're looking for with support for many languages, you can improve the dictionaries and it's really easy to integrate.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks but why must I use array_sum and array_map instead of strpos? Is it possible to use strpos as well because I am just learning about it at the moment

Comment: Can I also do the following instead? return strpos($first, $last, $password, $i) !== FALSE;

Comment: I see, it is using strpos but I also have to use array_map

Comment: I hope that I can add more than one variables as shown above

Comment: I have another weird problem and when I tried to sign up legitimately, it says that I still have a rude word...

Comment: I guess that I can always do more if statement with that but can I someone how put more than one variables in that code?

Comment: $offset = 0;
$find = array('retard', 'stupid', 'racist', 'bastard', 'fuck', 'fuck-off');
$first = "you're a fuckin' stupid";

if (array_sum(array_map(function ($i) use ($first, $last) {
    return strpos($first, $last,$i) !== FALSE;
}, $find)) > 0) {
    echo "BAD!";
}

Comment: I have got the following code but now it won't let me register

Comment: I got the above updated code but it won't let me register now with the correct credentials

Comment: I got it to work but I had to use that above statement a few times for each of my variable. I am just wondering if there is an easier way to include all variables into a single code? Something like below

Comment: $offset = 0;
$find = array('retard', 'stupid', 'racist', 'bastard', 'fuck', 'fuck-off');
$first = "you're a fuckin' stupid";

if (array_sum(array_map(function ($i) use ($first, $last) {
    return strpos($first, $last, $i) !== FALSE;
}, $find)) > 0) {
    echo "BAD!";
}

Comment: if you use the function I wrote for you it could be something like this: if (array_sum(array_map(function ($i) use ($badwords) { return has_bad_words($i, $badwords); }, $_POST)) > 0) { header("Location: Location: ../signup.php?signup2=badwords"); }

Comment: I haven't learn much about function yet though...... Is there another way to do it or I guess I don't mind using multiple codes